# Problemas con uso de libreria big-O en python

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un programa cualquiera pero lo que quiero es usar una librería llamada `big-O` para  evaluar mis funciones, la cuestión es que tengo una pregunta, ¿cuáles son las reglas de su uso? A lo que veo se necesita pasarle la función sin llamarla y un generador de datos pero por alguna razón lo que no entiendo es porque me da un error que me dice:

```
"TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'"
```

Digo si , debe ser un problema de comparación entre un entero y un dato tipo lista PERO no entiendo de donde sale el dato tipo lista? , es el generador? ¿qué clase de tratamiento le tengo que dar a las funciones que quiera evaluar para poder usar esa librería? Además, ¿qué datos son cambiables y cuáles son de sintaxis? ¿qué sucede si tengo una función con varios parámetros? ¿qué representa el `n` acá ?

Tengo muchas preguntas de cómo funciona esa librería.

Link de documentación: https://pypi.org/project/big-O/

Aqui esta el codigo:

```
    #Programa que calcula la serie de fibonacci recursivamente 
import big_o 

def fibonacci(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return n
    else:
        return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)


numero_terminos = 21

print(f"Serie de Fibonacci para los primeros {numero_terminos} términos:")
for i in range(numero_terminos):
    print(f"F({i}) = {fibonacci(i)}")

generator= lambda Z : big_o.datagen.integers(Z, 0, 1000)
Analysis = big_o.big_o(fibonacci, generator)
print (f" {Analysis}")
```

Comment: La función recibe una lista de valores que debe procesar. Debes hacer otra función que reciba la lista y ejecute `fibonacci` por cada valor. Llamala `fibonacci_O` y ejecuta `Analysis = big_o.big_o(fibonacci_O, generator)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*big_o* trata de encontrar la [complejidad temporal](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complejidad_temporal) de la función, la cual normalmente se expresa como una función del tamaño de la entrada (que es lo que representa la "N"). Para ello usa el tiempo de ejecución de dicha función y va incrementando el tamaño de su entrada, es un calculo empírico.

El problema es que estas usando la función generadora incorrecta para el tipo de dato que espera tu función (un entero). `big_o.datagen.integers` genera **una lista de enteros aleatorios** con la longitud determinada por `N`, (que es su  primer parámetro, valor de `Z` en tu caso). El error se produce porque `fibonacci` esta recibiendo como como parámetro `n` una lista, por lo que al ejecutar `if n <= 1:` esta haciendo algo como: `if [45, 17] <= 1:`, operación no definida para `int` y `list` como operandos.

Para generar un solo entero puedes usar `big_o.datagen.n_` que simplemente retorna `N` (básicamente equivalente a `lambda n: n`), por ejemplo:

```
analysis = big_o.big_o(
    fibonacci, big_o.datagen.n_, n_repeats=20, min_n=1, max_n=30
)
print(big_o.reports.big_o_report(*analysis))
```

Esto llamará a la función `fibonacci` pasandole como argumento los números del 2 al 30 (ambos incluidos), 20 veces por cada uno.

En cuanto a usar la big_o con funciones con mas de un parámetro, pues depende:

- Si la función tiene mas de un parámetro cuyo tamaño afecta a su tiempo de ejecución, como es el caso de una función que multiplique dos matrices (con lo que su rendimiento dependerá del tamaño de ambas), entonces la cosa es algo mas complicada:

  - [On Asymptotic Notation with Multiple Variables](https://people.cis.ksu.edu/%7Erhowell)
- Si tu función necesita de uno o varios parámetros que no influyen directamente en el calculo de la complejidad temporal, por ejemplo constantes, entonces puedes simplemente crear un envoltorio a la función. Por ejemplo, imagina que quieres calcular la complejidad de ordenar de forma invertida una lista mediante la función `sorted` de Python, por lo que necesitas usar el argumento `reverse`, es este caso puedes hacer algo como:

  ```
    big_o.big_o(
        lambda lista: sorted(lista, reversed=True),
        lambda n: big_o.datagen.integers(n, 10000, 50000)
        )
  ```

  al envolver con la función lambda a la función a evaluar puedes pasar los argumentos requeridos a esta a la vez que permites que el *callabl*e pasado a `big_o` reciba un solo argumento, la lista a ordenar. Como wrapper puedes usar lambda, funciones normales, [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)...